# How To Adapt Admin Template To MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, admin

I am developing a website and now want to create an admin panel and want to use this template

http://mvcadmintemplate.azurewebsites.net/

i download it, but it's a project.. So I have already a project, as an admin panel, i should add it in ARES folder. I copied the files from project hat i downloaded. but when i open admin panel (localhost/admin/home/index) it uses standart mvc template. as I see, it cant find the template files..

So I changed the bundleconfig.cs like that

```
namespace xxx
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Areas/Admin/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Areas/Admin/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Areas/Admin/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Areas/Admin/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Areas/Admin/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Areas/Admin/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Areas/Admin/Scripts/bootstrap.js"
                   , "~/Areas/Admin/Scripts/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"
                    ));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Areas/Admin/Content/css").Include("~/Areas/Admin/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));



            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Areas/Admin/bundles/vendors").Include(
  "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/uniform/jquery.uniform.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/chosen.jquery.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails-b3/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/wysihtml5.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails-b3/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/core-b3.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard-for.bootstrap3.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/boostrap3-typeahead/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails-b3/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/wysihtml5.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails-b3/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/core-b3.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/jGrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/flot/jquery.flot.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/flot/jquery.flot.selection.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"
  , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"
                 ));



            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme").Include(
                      "~/Areas/Admin/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Areas/Admin/Content/bootstrap-theme.css",
                      "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/css/bootstrap-admin-theme.css",
                       "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/css/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Areas/Admin/Content/Vendors").Include(
                "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css"
   , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/css/datepicker.fixes.css"
   , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/uniform/themes/default/css/uniform.default.min.css"
   , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/css/uniform.default.fixes.css"
   , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/chosen.min.css"
   , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails-b3/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-wysihtml5/core-b3.css"
   , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css"
   , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart_custom.css"
   , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails-b3/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-wysihtml5/core-b3.css"
   , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/jGrowl/jquery.jgrowl.css"
   , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css"
    , "~/Areas/Admin/Content/Theme/vendors/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css"));


        }
    }
}
```

bu this time it cant find also..

this is the directory..

[image]

so how i adapt the template to my admin areas?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I see its not been updated on github, I moved it to areas but, the route config is not mapping accurately to roles and admin areas at the same time